# HTML/CSS to PDF, background image on all pages

Tags: javascript, css, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm generating PDFs from user submitted HTML/CSS. The client has requested that the PDFs have a background image to add some branding. The PDF library is wkhtmltopdf11RC1.

I can make the images print in the background using the PDF conversion library but the real problem is that the height of the body is not guaranteed to be a multiple of the paper height, and so the last page usually get's cut off and the background image isn't shown.

The PDF library does have javascript support but the `element.offsetHeight` doesn't seem accurate, and so I can't check how much to pad the body by in order to make a full page.

Has anyone had a similar experience or does anyone have a bright idea?

Comment: Oh, that's a tough one. Can you post an image or PDF itself?

Comment: This is not a real solution, but you could perhaps look into post-processing the PDF (with something like PDFtk or even biting into the PDF format) and adding the background there. If you mange to go that route I would be very grateful if you cold post your findings!

Comment: I did wonder about something like this. Was going to try and maybe layer one PDF onto another. I'll look into it and let you know.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as @Nenotlep Imagemagick, convert and pdftk might be helpful here. I'm curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `var currentBodyHeight = $('body').height();` doesn't give an accurate indication of the height of the body for some reason, as mentioned in the original post. I've used PDFtk as suggested by Nenotlep.

It wasn't too tricky, just had to ensure that files were being saved and erased properly and I always kept a reference to the temporary files.

Comment: `$(document).height();` also gives an inaccurate measurement.

Comment: html, body {height:100%; margin:0} - it still returns an inaccurate body height?

Comment: Yes. Please believe me that I've spent a long time trying all these 'obvious' things. I'm looking for either a known fix to a known wkhtmltopdf issue or an out-of-the-box suggestion such as from Nenotlep. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin is relying on the height of the body to make printing decisions, than perhaps this will work. What it does is set the height of the body to a multiple of the page height. You are going to have to figure out what the paper height is - the standard is 72 pixels per inch. So 11.5 inches is something like 841 pixels, but you may have to adjust for margin.

```
var paperHeight = 841;

var currentDocHeight = $(document).height();

var pages = Math.ceil(currentDocHeight / paperHeight);

var newBodyHeight = pages * paperHeight;

$('body').css('height', newBodyHeight);
```

I've used jQuery to condense the answer, but this can all be done in jQuery-less javascript as well.

CSS:

```
body {
  margin:0
}
```

Comment: The calculation of a page height is very tricky in wkhtmltopdf; see the discussion section at http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=168